# populate dynamic form zend ramework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am bulding a web application using Zend Framework 2. The application retrieve some data from a db and shows it in a custom form. This data includes an array, whose length is variable. For each element of the array I need to show an input text in the form and set its label and value according to the element of the array it represents.

I have already my own custom form class, which extends the form base class, but I do not know where should I perform the operation of adding dynamic element. Should I do it in its constructor? Or in the *setData* method? Or anywhere else?

Comment: http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/

Comment: First link wasn't what you're looking for, just went by the Title... there you go: http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.collections.html